# emacs indentation problem with pp-macros

Tags: emacs

I cannot make emacs indent the following code properly. Somehow it cannot parse the preprocessor macros correctly. Any advise would be appreciated.

```
#ifdef WIN32
void func1()
#else
    void func1(int parameter)
#endif
{

    if (a > 2 || 
#ifdef WIN32
        (b < 3))
#else
        (b > 3))
#endif
        c = 1;
        else if (b > 2 || 
#ifdef WIN32
                 (a > 4))
#else
            (a < 4))
#endif
            c = 2;

mystatement;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Emacs will parse both parts of an `#if` `#else` construct. To get correct indentation, you have to make sure that you don't have unbalanced parentheses or braces. Concretely, you could rewrite the following:

```
if (a > 2 ||
#ifdef WIN32
    (b < 3))
#else
    (b > 3))
#endif
```

Into:

```
if (a > 2 ||
#ifdef WIN32
    (b < 3)
#else
    (b > 3)
#endif
    )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. I think this will help when developing new code. 

However, I have loads of existing code that I need to indent correctly.

I am beginning to understand that the problem is the syntactic analysis of emacs which cannot parse preprocessor macros correctly.

The solution could be if there is a way to force the analysis to use the same syntactic component for the line following "#else" as in the previous "#if"/"#ifdef"/"#ifndef". Has anyone got a clue how to do it?